# How to prove this equation? (FOLDR function)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ml

I have to prove this equation:

```
foldr f a (xs ++ ys) = foldr f (foldr f a xs) ys
```

I tried with induction but I couldn't manage to prove it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the RHS needs `xs,ys` to be swapped. See the answer to the duplicate question above.

Comment: You can expand [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) expressions in both sides to prove it directly.